# How to reset a filter of thedata set using pandas.isin

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning OOP programming in Python to automate my data science task. I have a filter that removes the value of the column. But when I'm calling my rest method it does nothing. Can someone help me?

I was trying with the .copy() function to save me current file but it didn't help. How do i fix it?

This is my code:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.df = self.read_csv()  # encapsulation of the read_csv() method.


    def read_csv(self):
        return pd.read_csv(self.url)

 def filter_out_lanes(self, column=None):
        if lanes is None:
            return self.df
        elif isinstance(column, int):
            column= [column]
        self.df = self.df[~self.df['column_id'].isin(column)]
        return self.df

  def reset_filter(self):
        # Reset to the original DataFrame
        self.df = self.df.copy()
        return self.df

main():
    class= Data('example.csv')
    class.filter_out_column([5, 6])
    print(class.histogram('column_id'))

    dwell_times.reset_filter()
    print(class.histogram('id'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is here:

```py
self.df = self.df[~self.df['column_id'].isin(column)]
```

as you've now *lost* the data in `self.df`. To get `reset_filter` working, I think you'll need something like this:

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.df = self.read_csv() 
        self.original_data = self.read_csv()
     ....

     def reset_filter(self):
        # Reset to the original DataFrame
        self.df = self.original_data.copy()
        return self.df
```

where you're now saving your original data as a separate variable.